# Using Java Web Start with JavaFX's Native Bundles

Tags: java, javafx, native, updates, java-web-start

I have developed a JavaFX app and I am going to distribute it as a [Native Package](https://blogs.oraclegha.com/talkingjavadeployment/entry/native_packaging_for_javafx) to avoid headaches with users having a Java version lower than 7 (and thus, without JavaFX) or having no Java at all.

However, I also want to be able to deliver updates of my application. One solution is for the app to call home (its already communicating with the backend via XMLRPC), fetch a JAR and self-update. I can see potential problems with the actual update process though (would need to build a separate updater program, but how do you update the updater?).

I know about and would **love** to use Java Web Start. However, I have no idea if this will work with the Native Package thing. If the user already has Java installed, it will disregard my bundled JRE. If he has no Java... well, he can't use Java Web Start, right?

How can I solve this problem in an elegant way that will not have a detrimental effect on user experience? (and preferably won't be very long to implement)

*note: I am using [e(fx)clipse](http://efxclipse.org/) as build tool.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If he has no Java... well, he can't use Java Web Start, right?

True, but as mentioned in the [JWS tag Wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info):

> [Java Rich Internet Applications Deployment Advice](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html).  Describes the `deployJava.js`
>   script designed to ensure a suitable minimum version of Java is installed before
>   providing a link to a
>   JWS app.
>   or launching an
>   applet.

Note that JWS also offers fine grained versioning as detailed in [Java Web Start - Runtime Versioning](http://pscode.org/jws/version.html).

Saying that, JWS *can* allow you to support earlier systems by adding the JavaFX 2 API selectively to those earlier systems.  That is achieved using a version based resources section in the launch file.

So, JWS combined with `deployJava.js` would actually be 'the alternative' to the Native Package that page discusses.

Comment: Can you clarify this a bit? Do you mean that if he has, say, Java 6, then using `depolyJava.js` + JWS, is he going to download just some extra JARs (presumably `jfxrt.jar`) or is JWS going to download and proceed to install, Java 7? Because I'm trying to avoid the latter.